# Switch Statement Not Executing Cases (c)

Tags: c, char, switch-statement, getchar

I made a switch statement, however, it only works with constants already set. If I try to use it with user input, only one of the cases work, every other one doesn't. Now no matter what I enter, it always uses the default case. I tried adding another getchar() to clear the `\n` character from the buffer but this isn't making a difference. Ill post the entire switch statement here :

```
      char option=' ';
      option=getchar();
      switch(option){

        //Parallel resistance calculations
        case 'p':
            CLEAR
            //PResistance();
            printf("RESISTANCE");
            getchar();
            break;

        //Ohm's Law calculations
        case 'o':
            CLEAR
            printf("OHM");
            //Ohm();
            break;

        //Exits program
        case 'q':
            printf("Good bye! Stay safe in the laboratory! :)\nPress any key to exit");
            getchar();
            exit(0);
            break;

        //Error checking
        default :
            printf("Invalid input, Try again"); 
            break;

    }


}
while (option!='q');
```

I commented out the functions so I could use the print statements to test if its working.

Comment: the switch will only match if option is a char variable.  If it is int there will be problems.  You could either change option to be char or you could use `switch(option & 0xFF){`

Comment: option is a char variable.

Comment: It will still match if `option` is an `int`. `getchar()` returns `int` anyway, and `'p'`, `'q'` etc. are ints.

Comment: @OP: change your default to `printf("Invalid input %d, try again", option);`. Then you will be able to see exactly what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you input a `character` or `string` from `stdin` in C, always make sure there is no `\n` in the input buffer. To do this, always `getchar()` after taking `integer` or `float` inputs.

In your case, maybe you've inputted an `integer` before inputting the `character`. So try to write a `getchar()` before taking the `character` input.

Comment: Thanks. Adding getchar() after each input fixed the issue.